# Face recognition attribute error in Python 3.6 version

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to run some face detect and face recognition code. But while I try to run the code for training data it shows some error. I am using Python 3.6 version and OpenCV module in Windows platform. I am adding code to first and error later.

[image: train the data]

and it shows following error:

```
C:\Users\MAN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.e‌​xe C:/Users/MAN/PycharmProjects/facerecognition/Train/train.py
Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:/Users/MAN/PycharmProjects/facerecognition/Train/train.py‌​", line 5, in <module> recognizer = cv2.createLBPHFaceRecognizer()
    AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'createLBPHFaceRecognizer'
    Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the error there. Also add your code as text, not as an image.

Comment: [I downvoted because images of code are not useful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode), and [because you're being unresponsive to comments](http://idownvotedbecau.se/beingunresponsive) - you were asked to replace the image of code with actual text a long time ago and didn't do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use it from the `face` submodule. So, try the following statement:

```
cv2.face.createLBPHFaceRecognizer()
```

instead of `cv2.createLBPHFaceRecognizer()`

Answer (score 0):

You should also install opencv-contrib module

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```